# Why does my glaze soak into my doughnuts?

Tags: baking, glaze, doughnuts

I fried up some yummy doughnuts and let them cool. Shortly after glazing them, I noticed that the glaze has soaked into the doughnuts. How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Okay, I did some more thorough searching and found [Beki Cook's donut frosting recipe](http://bekicookscakesblog.blogspot.com/2013/06/donut-frosting-recipes.html). Apparently my mistake was that I was letting them (the doughnuts) cool off, and according to the article:

> Glaze is the easiest way to sugar-up a donut. But there are a few things you need to remember. First and foremost... only glaze donuts when they're warm. If you do it when they've cooled the glaze just soaks in and get goopy.

Comment: Nice Q&A for your first appearance here! :) I think you even get a badge for that! Welcome to Seasoned Advice.